# In COGNOS report studio how can i search for columns by text

Tags: find, cognos

In Query studio i use ctrl + F and then type the text and the pane on the left hand side is highlighted. I once by accident found a way to search for a text in report studio but a normal control F does not work the way i want it to, which is just how control F works on any browser

Comment: There are some major problems with your question:
What version of Cognos?  What actual product?  (Cognos Planning, Cognos Business Intelligence, Cognos Analytics, etc.)
Define "columns".  Do you mean you want to find a column in a list?  Are you looking for a query item in the source pane?

Comment: It is in COGNOS Analytics. As for columns i basically have a pool of variables on the left side in report studio, lets say about 400. Thats a big number to look for one by one. Lets say i'm looking for column called "Last Name". I want to use a key similar to ctrl + F that would allow me to type "Last Name" column from the pool and not have me look one by one. Ctrl + F here gives me other options.

Comment: Now you're using "variables" and "columns" interchangeably.  What are you asking about?  Vocabulary matters.  I suspect what you are asking about is query items or data items.  Please update the question with more precise language using vocabulary found in the Cognos Analytics documentation.

Comment: Query studio is great, however with Cognos 11.1.7  this is a standard feature.  Is upgrading an option?

Comment: Not asking for the query items, but I guess the items that would make up a query item?

Comment: A query item is the lowest level thing you can see in the source pane.  So you do you mean you want to search the metadata?  ...get the design language names of the active language items you're seeing?  Or perhaps get the physical name (from the database) or Cognos expression for the query item as it's defined in the Framework Manager model?  Or do you not know what a query item is?  Again -- vocabulary matters.

Comment: @dougp i wouldn't know the proper vocabulary. I would just like to search the words on the page the way I would search words on this page, just control F. I did it by mistake but control F won't work without it being specific. I don't want specific, i want a general text search.

Comment: So you're asking about searching for text in the report output?